# How can I remove photos from an iPad Min without having to restore it?

Tags: ipad, photos, ipados

My iPad mini is overloaded with pictures.  I would like to delete them without having to restore the device and lose years of my iBook annotations. Is there a way to get these photos off my iPad mini without having to restore the device? I wish Apple would make it easier to simply delete photos from an iPad mini, but until that day I hope you can provide some options for us.

Comment: Why can't you simply delete the photos in the Photos app (both from the Roll and then from the Deleted Photos album)?

Answer (score 1):

What you ask it trivial on iOS 9. Enable cloud photos in iCloud settings if you haven't already. Once it's synced, turn of the library.

Select **Remove** and you are done.

If for some reason you can't or won't do that, connect to a Mac and you can use Image Capture app over USB to bulk delete. I suppose a PC version of the tool would exist, but that's not my area of expertise.

Also, you can select entire moments to delete on iOS 9 so even the manual method isn't a 1 to 1 tap to delete operation.